# Is there any short proof of Fatou's lemma?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there any short proof of **Fatou's  lemma**?

I found the proof [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/fatou-s-lemma-for-nonnegative-measurable-functions)    but its   very long proof

I need short proof of  **Fatou's  lemma**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions defined on $X$. Then we know the function $g(x)=\liminf f_n(x)$ is a measurable function, and we want to prove $\displaystyle\int_X g\,\text{d}\mu\le\liminf\int_X f_n\,\text{d}\mu$, this is, $\displaystyle\int_X \liminf f_n\,\text{d}\mu\le\liminf\int_X f_n\,\text{d}\mu$.

For each $k\in\Bbb N$ consider $g_k(x)=\inf_{k\ge n}f_n(x)$. Then $g(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}g_k(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\inf_{n\ge k}f_n(x)=\liminf f_n(x)$ (remember the $f_n$ are nonnegative).

Now, $g_k(x)=\inf_{n\ge k}f_n(x)\le f_(x)$ for every $n\ge k$, so by monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral we have $\displaystyle\int_X g_k\,\text{d}\mu\le\int_X f_\,\text{d}\mu$ for all $n\ge k$, hence we can take infimum on the right, $\displaystyle\int_X g_k\,\text{d}\mu\le\inf_{n\ge k}\int_X f_n\,\text{d}\mu$.

Note that $g_k(x)=\inf_{n\ge k}f_n(x)\le g_{k+1}(x)=\inf_{n\ge k+1}f_n(x)$, so $g_k$ is a nondecreasing sequence of nonnegative functions. Moreover $\lim_{k\to\infty}g_k(x)=g(x)$ pointwise, so we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Then $\displaystyle\int_X \liminf f_n\,\text{d}\mu=\int_X g\,\text{d}\mu=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_X g_k\,\text{d}\mu\le\lim_{k\to\infty}\inf_{n\ge k}\int_X f_n\,\text{d}\mu=\liminf\int_X f_n\,\text{d}\mu$.

This is the standard proof using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, making it shorter that the one you saw.